# Boost in VS2010 Express - redefinition and invalid calling convention errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, compiler-errors

I am using VS2010 Express and just installed Boost v1_47. I have added the 'include' folder to 'additional include folders' option, and also the 'lib' folder to the 'additional libraries' option in VS.

Then, I included boost/regex.hpp in one of my files, but actually wrote no code using boost yet. However, when building the solution I get lots of error messages, coming in two flavours:

- Redefiniton errors, such as:

1>D:\boost\boost_1_47\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp(83): error C2373: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer' : redefinition; different type modifiers
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\include\winnt.h(2597) : see declaration of '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer'

- Invalid calling convention errors (lots of these), such as:

D:\boost\boost_1_47\boost/regex/v4/regex_traits_defaults.hpp(271): error C3641: 'boost::re_detail::global_lower' : invalid calling convention '__cdecl ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe

Note: I haven't explicitly included winnt.h in any of my source/header files, and have tried de-activating pre-compiled headers and removing the stdafx.h includes, but it didn't solve the problem.

What's going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you compile your program with the same settings as boost.
It seems like you used the wrong project template (CLR something) to create your application project.

You could try to modify the properties of your existing project to make it compatible with boost, but the `CLR ...` projects have lots of incompatible property values set by default, so i think the easiest way would be to create a new project from scratch (and import your existing code).

You should use the "Empty Project" template and create a new project, and then add your existing source and header files to it, and add the boost include path again, and add any required boost .lib files to `Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` (Most boost libraries work out of the box without adding anything to linker inputs because they are header only, so you might not need to add any .libs).

Boost is a C++ required, designed to be consumed by C++ code, not C++/CLI code, thus it can only be used with native C++ classes, and most boost headers will produce headers when included in a source file which contains C++/CLI code.

Comment: Hi smerlin, thanks for your reply.
If I try what you suggest, starting with an empty project, and then importing my files, I get a huge pile of problems.
The first one is that the System namespace and those derived from it are not defined. I don't know how to solve this (I haven't used VS since 2001!). Any suggestions?

Comment: Than you code is not C++  but "C++ CLI" and thus you cant use boost. C++ does not have a `System` namespace. In each .cpp file you can either use C++/CLI (and therefore the System namespace) OR boost. If you want to use the System namespace you have to enable the "Common Langauge Runtime Support", for boost you have to disable it.

Comment: Um, that's very annoying :(
I was banking on using the boost thread infrastructure, as I haven't got (and will not pay for) MFC. But then I cannot use forms (which I need). It seems that I'll have to go back to NetBeans/Eclipse...
Thanks for your help, smerlin

Comment: When you already use CLR why dont you use thread classes it offers?

Comment: To be honest: I don't know the CLR model. I might have to research it a bit.
Anyway, I got the compiler to work with boost, but still have problems because it keeps trying to use the 32bit libraries, despite the fact that I have compiled the 64bit ones. But that's material for another thread... :)
Thanks again, smerlin